# What manager is suggested for Gallery Manager?

Tags: layout, blackberry, blackberry-jde, fieldmanager

I am working on implementing a gallery, I tried GridFieldManager for this, but the images of the thumbnail are not of same size. I sneaked through the gridfieldclass but there are no methods for making the cell size of each image constant.
Is it worth to use flowfieldmnager? When I tried overriding sublayout method for the above two managers it is not giving the desired reults.

Is it possible to sublayout flowfieldmanager?

Device : Blackberry 9780, OS 6.0

The below image is the desired result I am trying to get

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use a simple FlowFieldManager. But instead of BitmapField inside it, extend a Field to do the following:

- setExtent to 1/4 of the Display width in the sublayout method
- draw your own focus in the border of the image
- draw your own borders and draw the image in the center of the field's extent

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion, I solved this with a similar method, just posting how I solved it, hoping that it might use someone else..I used constant thumbnail sizes(BitmapField), and to make the focus visible on the Bitmapfield I set frame for the every bitmapfield and changed the frame color for the bitmapfield on which focus is..